# Evaluate $\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to know if my result is correct :
$$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx$$

So the region to integrate is 
$$R:=\left\{ (x,y)  \mid 0<y<\sqrt{9-x^2} \text{ and } -3<x<3 \right\}$$

After converting in polar coordinates,
$$R:= \left\{ (r, \theta) \mid 0<r<3 \text{ and } 0<\theta<\pi \right\}$$

Then,
\begin{align}
\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx 
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} r\sin(r^2) \, dr \, d\theta \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left[ \cos(r^2) \right]_{0}^{3} \, d\theta \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( \cos(9) - 1 \right) \, d\theta \\ 
&= -\frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos(9) \cdot \theta - \theta \right]_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2} \left( \cos(9) - 1 \right)
\end{align}

I don't like $\cos(9)$, that's why I don't think my answer is right. Can you help me!?

Comment: This is very correct, indeed ! Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your calculation and I think it correct.